# Rally SDK 2 manually filter or specify rallycardboard columns displayed

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I am trying to create a simple rallycardboard app that displays projects as columns with the project backlog stories as cards. Then allow the drag/drop of cards to set the project. Code is attached.

If I specify 'Project" as the attribute, the board contains columns for all projects in the workspace. I wish to limit the columns shown to either

1. Scoped parent and children, or
2. Code a list of project columns. I have tried the manipulate the columns, columnConfig, context settings, but nothing produces the desired results.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>CardBoard Example</title>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc2/sdk.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">
           Rally.onReady(function() {
               Ext.define('ProjBoard', {
                   extend: 'Rally.app.App',

                   launch: function() {
                       if (cardBoardConfig) {
                           cardBoardConfig.destroy();
                       }

                       var cardBoardConfig = {
                           xtype: 'rallycardboard',
                           types: ['User Story'],
                           attribute: 'Project',
                           fieldToDisplay: 'Project',
                           cardConfig: {
                               fields: ['Project', 'Parent','Iteration']
                           },
                           storeConfig: {
                               filters: [
                                   { property: 'ScheduleState', operator: '<', value: 'In-Progress' },
                                   { property: 'Iteration', operator: '=', value: '' }
                               ],
                               sorters: [
                                   { property: 'Rank', direction: 'DESC' }
                               ],
                               //Specify current project and scoping
                               context: this.getContext().getDataContext()
                           }
                       };

                       this.add(cardBoardConfig);
                   }
               });
               Rally.launchApp('ProjBoard', {
                 name: 'Backlog Project Board'
               });
           });
       </script>
       <style type="text/css">
       </style>
   </head>
   <body></body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: What are you asking? Just limiting the columns to one of the 2 cases?

Comment: Yes, if I run this now in my test environment, I get a column for each project in my hierarchy. I wish to limit the columns displayed by either of the described methods. First approach would be to manually specify them (i.e. "Product A, Team 1, Team 2, Team 3").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to specify the columns via config:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard-cfg-columns

```
columns: [
    {
        value: '/project/12345',
        columnHeaderConfig: {
            headerTpl: '{project}',
            headerData: {project: 'Project 1'}
        }
    },
    //more columns...
]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I really had trouble unraveling the columns: syntax...Thanks!

Comment: I agree with you- I hadn't tried to make a board this way in quite awhile.  Pretty difficult to figure out!

Answer (score 0):

The code below allowed me to cut down a dozen of project columns to three. First I get current project and query a collection of its child projects to build an array of projects I want to have on the board (you may choose a different criteria for what projects you want on the board), and then I extended `Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard` to overwrite its `_buildColumnsFromModel` method where only columns that meet this condition are filtered in :

```
retrievedColumns = _.select(retrievedColumns, function(project){    
     return that.arrayOfProjectRefs.indexOf(project.value) != -1
});
```

Here is the full js file. Apart from those changes, this is your code.

```
    Ext.define('CustomApp', { extend: 'Rally.app.App', componentCls: 'app',
        launch: function() {
            var that = this;
            that.arrayOfProjectRefs = [];
            var p = this.getContext().getProject();
            Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                model: 'Project',
                fetch: ['Children'],
                filters:[
                    {
                        Property: '_ref',
                        value: p
                    }
                ],
                pageSize: 1,
                autoLoad: true,
                listeners: {
                    load: function(store, records) {
                        var project = records[0];
                        var childProjects = project.get('Children');
                        var childProjectsCount = project.get('Children').Count;
                        console.log('childProjectsCount', childProjectsCount);
                        that.arrayOfProjectRefs.push(project.get('_ref'));
                        project.getCollection('Children').load({
                            fetch: ['_ref', 'Name', 'State'],
                            callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                                Ext.Array.each(records, function(child) {
                                    console.log(child.get('_ref') + ' - ' + child.get('Name') + child.get('State'));
                                    if (child.get('State') === 'Open') {
                                        that.arrayOfProjectRefs.push(child.get('_ref'));
                                        --childProjectsCount;
                                        if (childProjectsCount === 0) {
                                            that._buildBoard();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        },

        _buildBoard:function(){
         var that = this;
        console.log('app._arrayOfProjectRefs', this.arrayOfProjectRefs);   
        Ext.define('ProjectCardboard', {extend: 'Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard',
          xtype: 'projectCardboard',

         _buildColumnsFromModel: function() {
                var model = this.models[0];
                if (model) {
                    var attribute = model.getField('Project');
                    if (attribute) {
                        attribute.getAllowedValueStore().load({
                            callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                                var retrievedColumns = _.map(records, function(allowedValue) {
                                    var displayValue, value = allowedValue.get('StringValue');
                                    if (!value && attribute.attributeDefinition.AttributeType.toLowerCase() === 'rating') {
                                        value = "None";
                                    } else if (attribute.attributeDefinition.AttributeType.toLowerCase() === 'object') {
                                        displayValue = value;
                                        value = allowedValue.get('_ref');
                                        if (value === 'null') {
                                            value = null;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    return {
                                        value: value,
                                        columnHeaderConfig: {
                                            headerTpl: displayValue || value || 'None'
                                        }
                                    };
                                });

                                this.fireEvent('columnsretrieved', this, retrievedColumns);

                                retrievedColumns = _.select(retrievedColumns, function(project){    
                                    return that.arrayOfProjectRefs.indexOf(project.value) != -1
                                });
                                 console.log('retrievedColumns after filter', retrievedColumns)
                                this.columnDefinitions = [];
                                _.each(retrievedColumns, this.addColumn, this);
                                this.renderColumns();
                            },
                            scope: this
                        });
                    }
                }
            }       
    }); 

            var addNewConfig = {
                xtype: 'rallyaddnew',
                recordTypes: ['User Story'],
                ignoredRequiredFields: ['Name', 'Iteration'],
                showAddWithDetails: false,
            };

            this.addNew = this.add(addNewConfig);
            var myCardConfig = {
                   xtype: 'rallycard',
                   fields: ['ScheduleState','Name'], 
                   maxHeight: 100
                } 

            var cardBoardConfig = {
                xtype: 'projectCardboard',
                types: ['User Story'], 
                attribute: 'Project', 
                cardConfig: myCardConfig
            };

            this.cardBoard = this.add(cardBoardConfig);
   }
});
```

Comment: I put this in Cloud9, using rally-app-builder. Created app, but board does not display. Chrome console has: childProjectsCount 0 no matter where I scope.